# How to validate length and match required character?

Tags: javascript, regex, html, web

I want to hide the submit button if value does not match the required type, I m able to hide it on the length, but my match does not work.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function submitChangej(){

var inputlastName = document.getElementById("lastname"); 
var inputfirstName = document.getElementById("firstname"); 
var inputmobileNumber = document.getElementById("mobilenumber");
var inputidNumber = document.getElementById("idnumber");
var firstname =  /^[a-zA-Z-\s]{2,128}$/; 
var lastname = /^[a-zA-Z-\s]{2,128}$/; 
var mobilenumber = /^[0-9]{10,20}$/;
var idnumber = /^([0-9]){2}([0-1][0-9])([0-3][0-9])([0-9]){4}([0-1])([0-9]){2}?$/;

var inputSubmit = document.getElementById("apply");

var Container = document.getElementById('Agreement');

if((inputfirstName.value.length < 2 || inputfirstName.value.length > 128 ) || ( inputlastName.value.length < 2 || inputlastName > 128 ) || (inputmobileNumber.value.length < 10 || inputmobileNumber > 20) || (inputidNumber.value.length < 13)){


        Container.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else{

        Container.style.display = 'block';
  }
  var Container = document.getElementById('Agreement');
 if((firstname.match(firstname) != null) || (lastname.match(lastname) != null) || (mobilenumber.match(mobilenumber) != null) || (idnumber.match(idnumber) != null)){

        Container.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else{

        Container.style.display = 'block';

  } 
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<form >

<label for="firstname"><span class="starRequired"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span>First name:</label><br> 
<input  type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"  required  autofocus="autofocus" pattern="[a-zA-Z-\s]{3,128}"  onkeyup="submitChangej();"  onkeypress="checkFirstname(this.value);" value="">

<br/><label for="lastname"><span class="starRequired"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span>Last name:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" required id="lastname"  pattern="[a-zA-Z-\s]{3,128}"  onkeyup="submitChangej();" onkeypress="checkLastname(this.value);" 
        onblur="checkLastname(this.value);" value="">  

<br/><label for="mobilenumber"><span class="starRequired"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span>Mobile Number:</label><br/>              
<input type="text" name="mobilenumber" required  id="mobilenumber" onkeyup="submitChangej();" onkeypress="checkMobilenumber(this.value);"
        onblur="checkMobilenumber(this.value);"  value="">

<br/><label for="idnumber">ID Number:</label><br/>  
<input type="text" name="idnumber" id="idnumber" maxlength="13" onkeyup="submitChangej();" onkeypress="checkIdnumber(this.value);" 
        onblur="checkIdnumber(this.value);" value="">

<div id="Agreement" style="display:none">               
<input type="submit" id="apply" name="apply"  value="Apply"  
onclick="if(!this.form.terms.checked){alert('Please indicate that you accept the Agreement');return false}"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" >    
<label id="accept" >I accept the Agreement</label>
<textarea  name="textfield" id="textfield"  rows="10" cols="105" readonly="readonly" >      
     1. Acceptance
     1.1 I have read and accepted the above terms and conditions.
        </textarea>
        </span>
      </div>

    </form>
```

I than call my method `submitChangej()`on the fields that i validate.

The button should be hidden when match and length are invalid, if everything is correct than the button should appear. The length work good, but the match of required characters does not match

Comment: This expression `firstname.match(firstname)` doesn't make sense since it matches regexp `firstname` against **itself**. Regexps have no `match` method, strings have. So I think it should be `inputfirstName.match(firstname)` instead.

Comment: I will try that and tell if it works

Comment: Correction: `inputfirstName.value.match(firstname)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the final lines of your code to:

```
if(!firstname.test(inputfirstName.value) || !lastname.test(inputlastName.value) || !mobilenumber.test(inputmobileNumber.value) || !idnumber.test(inputidNumber.value)){
    Container.style.display = 'none';
}
else {
    Container.style.display = 'block';
}
```

As it was already mentioned you're trying to find a match on a pattern itseld, which has no sense. Then, the **match** method is used to get a matching string, but you only want to test the string against some pattern, so use the **test** method instead.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @onerror. Your suggestion worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. You saved my time on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simplifying this and letting the browser do more of the leg work for you by putting this in a form on change listener:

```
inputSubmit.style.display = (document.querySelectorAll('*:invalid').length)? = 'none' : 'block';
```

Comment: Doing it this way avoids duplicating your regex patterns. Best to ONLY have them in the HTML attributes rather than having them in HTML and js and having to mirror changes in both.